# Xcode Instruments "Networking recording service not found"

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I want to use Xcode instruments to analyze network traffic of my iOS app.
Unfortunately instruments seems to be broken.

[image]

I already reinstalled Xcode (incl. Instruments).

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Used Versions:

- Xcode 9.4.1 (9F2000)
- Instruments 9.4.1 (9F2000)

Comment: What Xcode and Instruments version are you using?

Comment: XCode 9.4.1 (9F2000)
Instruments 9.4.1 (9F2000)

Comment: @ram did you share the correct link? This question isn't about getting dmg files...

Comment: Instruments 9.4.1 is definitely broken. I cannot use any template, even the blank one. It always complains it cannot use .tracetemplate files.

Comment: Any solution about this dude ?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, custom instruments not working with the simulator are a known issue.

There are few that works now, such as Leaks.

You always have the option to plug a real device, this will work.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the Network Connections instrument is installed when you install the Xcode 10 beta. I just verified that on my machine which has the beta installed Network Connection shows up while on another machine that has 9.4.1 but not the Xcode 10 beta it does not show up.

You might want to file a radar about this so Apple can look in to it...

Comment: still the same with version 10.0 (10L176w)

Comment: Since 10.0 is in its first Beta i would file a radar with Apple to make sure they have a look at this.

Comment: @donnywals I'm curious, are you able to open any tracetemplate, such as Allocations or Leaks?

Comment: I haven't found one that works so far.. very frustrating

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error when i was trying on iPhone Simulator and got it resolved it by running it on real device.

Answer (score 0):

**Delete all OLDER versions of Instruments from disk, as it was recommended in an Apple forum, and see if that helps.** For me, it worked. **I am now able to use Instruments 9.4.1.**

On my system, Xcode 9.4.1 was trying to launch an older version of Instruments, which crashed because it was trying to access a framework that no longer exists, namely:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreProfile.framework
```

and also caused the system to confuse UTI ownerships, and thus making impossible for Instruments 9.4.1 to open tracetemplate files.